# Dask array broadcasting seems to be incompatible with sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, dask

I'm working on an algorithm that uses Dask to avoid memory errors, since the data seems to be too big to handle on my computer. In one of the steps of the algorithm I want to use a coefficient (and sparse) matrix, `coefs` with shape `(M, N)`  and perform an element-wise multiplication on an array `T` with shape `(K, M, N)`, consisting of `K` `MxN` matrices. Since `coef` is a sparse matrix, I'd like to take that into account instead of working with the dense array.

I'm using the following configuration:

- Python version: 3.7.3
- Numpy version: 1.16.2
- Dask version: 1.2.0
- Scipy version: 1.2.1
- Sparse version: 0.7.0

I've tried three different possibilities.

#### Version 1

The matrix of coefficients is just a `numpy.ndarray` matrix.

#### Version 2

The matrix of coefficients is a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` matrix.

#### Version 3

The matrix of coefficients is a `sparse.coo.core.COO` matrix.

Reference: https://sparse.pydata.org/en/latest/

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import scipy.sparse as sp
import sparse

def func_test(coef):

    K, M, N, tol = 10, 2000, 800, 1e-7

    # Starting values
    P1 = np.random.rand(K,M)
    P1 /= P1.sum(1)[:, None]
    P2 = np.random.rand(K, N)
    P2 /= P2.sum(1)[:, None]
    P3 = np.random.rand(K)
    P3 /= P3.sum()

    # Convert arrays to dask
    P2 = da.from_array(P2, chunks=(1000))
    P3 = da.from_array(P3, chunks=(1000))

    # Threshold
    P1[P1 < tol] = tol
    P2[P2 < tol] = tol

    for iter_number in range(20):
        T = P3[:, None, None] * (P1[:, :, None] @ P2[:, None, :])
        T *= coef # Problematic line
        P1 = T.sum(2) / T.sum((1,2))[:,None]  # (K, M)
        P2 = T.sum(1) / T.sum((1,2))[:,None]
        P3 = T.sum((1,2)) / T.sum()
        # Threshold
        P1[P1 < tol] = tol
        P2[P2 < tol] = tol
    return T, P1, P2, P3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # coef is a numpy.ndarray
    M, N = 2000, 800
    coef_1 = np.random.random((M, N))
    # Make it sparse
    coef_1[coef_1 < 0.92] = 0
    # coef is a scipy.sparse matrix
    coef_2 = sp.csr_matrix(coef_1)
    # coef is a sparse COO matrix
    coef_3 = sparse.COO.from_numpy(coef_1)

    T, P1, P2, P3 = func_test(coef_1)

    T = T.compute()
```

The code will raise an error if the parameter passed to func_test is either `coef_2` or `coef_3`.

If the parameter is `coef_2` Python raises a ValueError:

```py
ValueError: could not interpret dimensions
```

If it is `coef_3` it raises another ValueError:

```py
ValueError: Please make sure that the broadcast shape of just the sparse arrays is the same as the broadcast shape of all the operands.
```

I've used `%timeit` on IPython to measure the execution time:

- With `coef_1`: `869 ms ± 52.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
- With `coef_2`: `322 ms ± 3.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
- With `coef_3`: `249 ms ± 2.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

My question is: is it possible to perform operations using Dask N-dimensional arrays with sparse matrices? The inplace assignment

```py
T *= coef
```

seems to save a lot of time.

#### Some notes

I've tried to use

```py
T = coef.multiply(coef_2)
```

but it increases the execution time:

```py
4.65 s ± 173 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

- The values of `M` and `N` will be bigger than those shown in the code, hence the dask requirement.
- I'm using Dask, but suggestions are welcomed. Particularly, the operation:

```py
T = P3[:, None, None] * (P1[:, :, None] @ P2[:, None, :])
```

causes a `MemoryError` on my computer when the matrices are too big.

Comment: Why the `pydata` link?  I don't see a related `import`?

Comment: How much of this works without the `dask` layer?  I haven't used `dask`.  Keep in mind that `scipy.sparse` matrices are not `numpy` `ndarray` subclasses, so `numpy` (and probably `dask`) doesn't know anything about it - unless they defer to sparse methods.  '*' is matrix multiplication for sparse, though what is used in the `T*=coef` expression is not clear.  Does `T*=coef.A` work?

Comment: I should add, the numpy broadcasting does not apply to `scipy.sparse` matrices.

Comment: The related import is ```import sparse```. As for the ```dask``` layer, it is used mainly to deal with T.

Comment: The line ```T *= coef``` is used to perform an element-wise multiplication. Each of the ```K``` ```MxN``` matrices is multiplied element-wise by the coefficient matrix. As for the suggestion  ```T *= coef.A```, it works with  ```coef_2``` , but the execution time is almost the same as when I use the ```coef_1``` version.